Calculating distance between rows of Pandas dataframe and adding to list
The question I'm asking is similar to the one I posted here a while ago: Comparing 2 Pandas dataframes row by row and performing a calculation on each row
I got a very helpful answer to that question and I'm trying to use that information to help me answer my current question.
Task: Group a dataframe by columns trial, RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL, and IP_INDEX. For each group, I need to calculate the Euclidean distance between a row and all rows above it (so from Row 2 to Row n) using the values in columns CURRENT_FIX_X and CURRENT_FIX_Y. If the distance is less than 58.93, I need to add the value of CURRENT_FIX_INDEX from the row I'm comparing to (not against) to a list, and then concatenate that list into a string and add it to a new column (refix_list) so the string is in the new column of the row I'm comparing against.
Example: I'm on Row 7, so I'm comparing the distance of Row 7 to Rows 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, and 1 of that group. If the distance between Row 7 and Rows 5, 3, and 1 are less than 58.93, I want a  comma-separated string that contains the CURRENT_FIX_INDEX value of each of those 3 rows in the refix_list column at Row 7.
Problem: I have code that I'm working with, and I'm not sure if it's working because I get a 'ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (297)' when I try to print the df so I know there's an issue either creating the list or more likely, concatenating it into a string and assigning it to the specific row.
Here's the code I'm working with (with sample data for 1 participant):
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_df = {
    'IP_INDEX': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    'RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
    'trial': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'CURRENT_FIX_INDEX': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'CURRENT_FIX_X': [550, 575, 250, 300, 500, 475, 275, 550, 675, 650, 800, 325, 450, 400, 375, 650, 700, 675, 825, 400, 375, 150],
    'CURRENT_FIX_Y': [275, 250, 600, 650, 300, 325, 675, 300, 850, 875, 250, 625, 225, 150, 675, 250, 300, 275, 150, 225, 250, 650]

}

# Create DF1
df = pd.DataFrame(data_df)

# Define a function to calculate Euclidean distance
def euclidean_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return np.sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)

# Grouping the DataFrame by RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL, trial, and IP_INDEX
grouped = df.groupby(['RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL', 'trial', 'IP_INDEX'])

# List to store CURRENT_FIX_INDEX for each row
index_list = []
refix_values = []

# Iterate over each group
for group_name, group_df in grouped:
    # Sort the group_df by some unique column
    group_df = group_df.sort_values(by='trial')
    
    # Calculate Euclidean distance for each row
    for i, row in group_df.iterrows():
        current_x = row['CURRENT_FIX_X']
        current_y = row['CURRENT_FIX_Y']
        
        # Calculate distance with every row above it
        for j, prev_row in group_df.iloc[:i].iterrows():
            current_index = prev_row['CURRENT_FIX_INDEX']
            prev_x = prev_row['CURRENT_FIX_X']
            prev_y = prev_row['CURRENT_FIX_Y']
            
            distance = euclidean_distance(current_x, current_y, prev_x, prev_y)
            
            # If distance is less than or equal to 58.93, store CURRENT_FIX_INDEX
            if distance <= 58.93:
                index_list.append(current_index)
    refix_values.append(','.join(map(str, index_list))) #Add list of matching INDEX values to list of lists

df['refix_list'] = []

# Iterate over the DataFrame to access each row and its index
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Assign the list to the current row in the specified column
    df.at[index, refix_list] = refix_values

print(df)

Expected Output:



IP_INDEX
RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL
trial
CURRENT_FIX_INDEX
CURRENT_FIX_X
CURRENT_FIX_Y
refix_list




1
a
1
1
550
275



1
a
1
2
575
250
1


1
a
1
3
250
600



2
a
1
1
300
650



2
a
1
2
500
300



2
a
1
3
500
325
2


2
a
1
4
275
675
1


2
a
1
5
550
300
3, 2


3
a
1
1
675
850



3
a
1
2
650
875
1


3
a
1
3
800
250



4
a
1
1
325
625



1
a
2
1
450
225



1
a
2
2
400
150



2
a
2
1
375
675



3
a
2
1
650
250



3
a
2
2
700
300



3
a
2
3
675
275
2, 1


4
a
2
1
825
150



4
a
2
2
400
225



4
a
2
3
375
250
2


4
a
2
4
150
650




From my limited knowledge, I'm guessing the issue is in the last block of code, but I'm not positive. Any help is appreciated!

you should provide data of what your input/output data is supposed to look like

Are you entirely sure of roe 8? ````2 a 1 5 550 300 3, 2``` ?

@SergedeGossondeVarennes yes. The distance between row 8 and rows 5&6 is less than the specified amount. Since I need the data to be grouped by trial, recording_session_label, and ip_index, the calculation for row 8 would stop at row 4. Thus, it wouldn't check if row 8 matched with any rows above that.
